# Compiling KBMMW design package in Delphi 10.3: vcl conflict error (E2199)

Tags: vcl, delphi-10.3-rio

I have Delphi 10.3 community edition and kbmMW Enterprise installed.
I'm trying to compile the kbmmw design package (kbmwdes103Ent) with Delphi 10.3 Community edition, but I get the following error: [dcc64 Error] kbmMWDesD103Ent.dpk(36): E2199 Packages 'kbmMWRunD103Ent' and 'vcl' both contain unit 'Vcl.Grids'.
Any idea how fix this conflict issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure vcl is in the requirements section of both the kbmMWDesD103Ent and kbmMWRunD103Ent package projects.

Comment: I tried to put vcl in the requirements section  of both package, but now I get the similar error in the other unit: [dcc32 Error] kbmMWDesD103Ent.dpk(36): E2199 Packages 'kbmMWRunD103Ent' and 'vclimg' both contain unit 'Vcl.Imaging.pngimage'

Comment: Hi,
The problem is that Delphi has for many years now been horrible in automatically suggest requirements to be added. I have reported this many times to Embarcadero, but they unfortunately have not figured out why, since it is not constant.

Next version of kbmMW will include a CompileTool which will handle it all automatically and make it easy to compile kbmMW again.

Until then you need to add: rtl, vcl, vclimg, vclx, fmx, dbrtl, vcldb, kbmMemRunD103Pro to the runtime package and designtime package.

Further you need to add: designide and kbmMWRunD103Ent to the designtime package.

Comment: If you are using FireDAC, also add FireDAC, FireDACCommon, FireDACCommonDriver, vclFireDAC to the runtime package.
If you are using ADOExpress also add adortl to the runtime package.

If you are using other database components you will need to add their library name to the runtime package requirements section too.

Comment: Adding  add: rtl, vcl, vclimg, vclx, fmx, dbrtl, vcldb, kbmMemRunD103Pro to the runtime package and designtime package, I was able to compile and install the kbmmw desdigntime package. Thanks.